# how to open 3 input files one by one without opening grads?

Tags: grads

I have a some dat files which I have generated using java code.
I have 3 different input files to show images in grads.
I have written a .sh file which first executes my java program and then opens grads. Now to execute 3 files in grads, I write exec file1.inp..after its executions I write exec file2.inp and then exec file3.inp.
Is there any way so that I do not have to write 3 exec commands for 3 different files. If I can write these commands in another file and execute that file.
I am saving the images so I do not want grads to show the images

Comment: Have u tried the grads -b command?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an alternative you could use to save these images, however you will need grads to display them first. There is a command called "printim" which allows you to save any data displayed on the GrADS display to an image file(PNG, GIF, JPEG). I personally am unfamiliar with .inp files, but you could write a grads script file(.gs) and run that within the grads prompt. With that, you should be able to automate the reading and saving of the your figures from the .dat file.

[Documentation for printim](http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/gadoc/gradcomdprintim.html)

[Grads Scripting Introduction](http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/gadoc/script.html)

Hopefully this helps!